# Is it reasonable to claim the power set of the natural numbers, ${\mathcal {P}}(\mathbb{N})$, is the largest possible σ-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: measure-theory

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#Definition) gives this definition of sigma-algebra

> Let X be some set, and let ${\mathcal {P}}(X)$ represent its power set. Then a subset ${\displaystyle \Sigma \subseteq {\mathcal {P}}(X)}$ is called a σ-algebra if it satisfies the following three properties:
>
> 1. X is in Σ, and X is considered to be the universal set in the following context.
> 2. Σ is closed under complementation: If A is in Σ, then so is its complement, X \ A.
> 3. Σ is closed under countable unions: If $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ are in Σ, then so is $A = A_1 ∪ A_2 ∪ A_3 ∪ …$ .
>
> since {X, ∅} satisfies condition (3), it follows that {X, ∅} is the smallest possible σ-algebra on X. The largest possible σ-algebra on X is $2^X:= {\mathcal {P}}(X)$

Based on which, is it reasonable to claim the power set of the natural numbers, ${\mathcal {P}}(\mathbb{N})$, is the largest possible σ-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: As your quote says: The power set is the largest $\sigma$-algebra for every set. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is a set, your claim is true.

Comment: Yes.First of all, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ is a $\sigma-$algebra. If $\Sigma$ is any $\sigma-$algebra on $\mathbb N$, then we have  $\Sigma\subset\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ by definition. So  $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ is the largest $\sigma-$algebra on $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is reasonable, provided you use a reasonable definition of biggest. $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is the biggest in the sense that for any $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ over $\mathbb{N}$ there is a natural inclusion map $i: \Sigma \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. Don't try to define 'biggest' via size or cardinality, that could get messy.